# Anyone know similar software like audiomotors?

Tags: car, engine

Anyone know similar software like ***"audiogaming audiomotors"*** ? 
This stuff very good but too expensive for me.
Thanks the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there are cheaper versions of this type of software! I could be wrong though.

Have you tried using something like Unity, UT3ed or an API like Wwise to recreate the implementation of an engine?

You could also create a procedural engine using Pure Data or Max MSP I think the book Designing Audio by Andy Farnell has a detailed description of how to accomplish this using Pure Data.

Good luck.